# How to write a query that lists the name of someting that appears in more than one category

Tags: sql

I'm new so please excuse me if this is a dumb question but i can't figure it out.
Question: Write a query that lists the name of Products that appear in more than one Recipe.
These are the tables
[image: tables]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution to this question is to use a `GROUP BY` expression with a `HAVING` clause to limit the results to groups that have a count of more than 1

```
SELECT Nome_produto
FROM Receita
LEFT JOIN Ingrediente ON Receita.Codigo_receita = Ingrediente.Codigo_receita
LEFT JOIN Produto ON Ingrediente.Codigo_produto = Produto.Codigo_produto 
GROUP BY Nome_produto
HAVING COUNT(Receita.Codigo_receita) > 1
```

| Nome_produto |
| --- |
| Ovos |

The key to solving an issue like this is to first build the relationship between the entities that the requirement refers to, in this case I'm selecting data `FROM` the recipe table first, as this is the *subject* that the principal predicate must be applied to:

> ...that appear in more than one Recipe.

Once you have a denormalized or *flat* table of results, we can apply the *grouping* with a `HAVING` clause. `HAVING` is similar to `WHERE` except that it is evaluated *after* the grouping and allows us to use the results from *aggregate expressions* in conditional statements.

> `WHERE` is applied to individual rows and will exclude rows *before* the grouping sets are realized and therefore before *aggregates* are evalutated.

- Read more about [**SQL HAVING Clause** *here* @ W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp).